# How to start geolocation on firebaseAuth success

Tags: authentication, geolocation, angularfire

I'm using $firebaseAuth to control the login part of my application and I want to launch a geolocation when user is authenticate.

Geolocation start before the authentication when I use the code below :

```
 .run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $location, Auth, $ionicLoading, $cordovaGeolocation, geoLocation, defautLocation) {
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

       if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
             cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
     if (window.StatusBar) {
       // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
     }

     $rootScope.firebaseUrl = firebaseUrl;
     $rootScope.displayName = null;

     Auth.$onAuth(function (authData) { 
        if (authData) {
            console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
        } else {
            console.log("Logged out");
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    })

    $cordovaGeolocation
      .getCurrentPosition()
      .then(function (position) {
         ...
      }, function(err) {
         ...
             });
     $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition({
         frequency: 1000,
         timeout: 3000,
         enableHighAccuracy: false
    }).then(function () {
    }, function (err) {
       ...
    });

    $rootScope.logout = function () {
        console.log("Logging out from the app");
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Logging Out...'
        });
        Auth.$unauth();
}

...
```

I try to wrap $cordovaGeolocation :

```
 Auth.$requireAuth().then(function(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    $cordovaGeolocation
      .getCurrentPosition()
      .then(function (position) {
         ...
      }, function(err){
         ...
     });
     $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition({
         frequency: 1000,
         timeout: 3000,
         enableHighAccuracy: false
    }).then(function () {
    }, function (err) {
       ...
    });
  }else{
     ...
  }
  });
```

But when user sign in it doesn't launch the geolocation, I need to reload.

watchPosition means my function have to be active all time during authentication.

So my question is, how I can execute my geolocation function just after the authentication success and until unAuth() ?

(I'm new on Angular and Firebase, no surprise)

Thx a lot,

Comment: You'll probably want it in `Auth.$onAuth`, i.e. where you already have `console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);`

Comment: You're true.. shame on me.. My problem now is to stop watchingPosition on unAuth, I try a clearWatch in logout function but still watching..

Thx !

Comment: That code would go into the `else` branch on the `$onAuth` function.

Comment: Yes but when I auth a first time and then unauth, watchPosition stop and I reach my login page which stored my user name and password, I auth again, watchPosition fire again then I unauth again and watchPosition don't stop whereas I'm unauth.. It works once not twice, I have to refresh my page after first unauth..

Comment: Thx for your help, my last comment concerns probably an other problem so I have ask a new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342097/controller-not-initilized-at-second-authentication).